# Trouble with Creating a Job for Bulk API 2.0

Tags: bulk-api, c#

I'm Using this documentation [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/create_job.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/create_job.htm#topic-title)

With this URI https://cs30.salesforce.com/services/async/44.0/jobs/ingest

And this payload {"operation":"insert","object":"Account","contentType":"CSV"}

I am using C# to connect and get a job, from everything I've read so far this should be working.

```
request.Method = method;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.AccessToken);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
{
   UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
   byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(body);
   request.ContentLength = data.Length;
   using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
   {
      newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   }
}
```

.. Continues to make the request

So my question is I keep getting a 400 Bad Request with this, What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `/services/data/vXX.X/jobs/ingest`?

Comment: I've tried this as well https://cs30.salesforce.com/services/async/44.0/jobs/ingest, sorry I Need to edit my question that is misleading.

Comment: You have `/services/async` in your URL, whereas the documentation mentions it should be `/services/data`, have you tried changing that?

Comment: Your not going to believe this but it was because i was missing the 'v' in-front of version. Its just one of those days. Thank you for pointing that out, It lead to me just copy and pasting the darn thing in, cause I just couldn't get it right

Comment: You may like to add that as an answer to be able to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was missing the 'v' in-front of version.